How to add stacked bar plot in a subplot in Plotly?
I have a data frame df, it has over 100 columns, I want to plot a stacked bar plot for these 100 columns, plotly.express is very nice, I can just do this
import plotly.express as px
# df.columns = ['date', 'val1', 'val2', ..., 'val100', 'cost', 'numSales']
cols_to_be_stacked = df.columns[1:-2]
px.bar(df, x='time', y=cols_to_be_stacked)

But I want to have a subplots with (numRows=2, numCols=1), where the two rows share the x axis,
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

## Q1: how should I do my_stacked_bar_plot for 100 columns?
fig.add_trace(my_stacked_bar_plot, row=1, col=1)

# Q2: I want to add time-cost plot to the y-axis on the right side, how 
# should I write the line below?
# In matplotlib, i can just use ax.twinx().
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'].values, y=df['cost'].values), row=1, col=1)

## now plot the time-numSales on 2nd row.
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'].values, y=df['numSales'].values), row=2, col=1)


Can someone help me with Q1 and Q2 in the comments above? Or is there another way to achieve this other than using add_trace?
Thanks!
Edit(shorter description as below)
As a simple illustration, if I have a df like this (here I have only 6 of val columns instead of 100 val columns
df = pd.DataFrame([[20240502, -2, 3, -3, 7, -9, 6, 6, 8], 
[20240503, 4, -6, -5, 7, -3, -2, 12, 9]], 
columns=["date", 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 
'val5', 'val6', 'cost', 'numSales'])

    
       date  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  cost  numSales
0  20240502     2     3    -3    -7     9     6     6         8
1  20240503     4    -6     5     7    -3     8    12         9


I want to a plot like below, (x-axis is shared for the top and bottom subplot)


Could you please share some reproducible data using dput?

Just did it with a simple df

Explain the points addressed for your purposes. First, as a subplot specification, the second axis is enabled by a combination of bar and xy graphs. The x-axis is also set to shared. The graph is looped, processing one line of data using the bar chart's relative mode. The legend will be duplicated, so the legend will be grouped. At the same time, the legend of the second row is hidden. Currently the z-order is not adjustable in plotly, so if you want the line chart to show a little, you will need to adjust the transparency of the bar chart colors.
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,
                    shared_xaxes=True,
                    specs=[
                        [{'type': 'bar', 'type': 'xy', 'secondary_y': True}],
                        [{'type': 'xy'}]
                    ])

for i,col in enumerate(df.columns[1:-2]):
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[df.loc[0,'date']],
                         y=[df.loc[0, col]],
                         name=col,
                         marker_color=colors[i],
                         legendgroup=col)
                  , secondary_y=True, row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[df.loc[1,'date']],
                         y=[df.loc[1, col]],
                         name=col,
                         marker_color=colors[i],
                         legendgroup=col,
                         showlegend=False),
                  secondary_y=True, row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_layout(barmode='relative')

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'].values,
                         y=df['cost'].values,
                         name='cost',
                         legendgroup='cost'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'].values,
                         y=df['numSales'].values,
                         name='numSales',
                         legendgroup='numSales'), row=2, col=1)

fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, legend_tracegroupgap=5)
fig.show()



Hi, thanks for showing this, the plot shown is indeed as expected. But I am looking for a way similar to px.bar(df, x='time', y=100_cols_to_be_stacked),  i.e.,  not  by looping over  100 columns to plot each bar. I wonder why go.Bar doesn't have a similar interface as px.bar.
